# Scenarios for library that will be used by developers

Tags: bdd

I've started learning BDD but I think I have some misunderstanding of how to use it correctly.

Currently I'm writing an API for a product. This API will be used by other developers only. Is it ok to write features and scenarios from the developer point of view? Something like:

```
Feature: Authorization
    In order to access program runtime
    As a module developer
    I want to ensure that authorization is done correctly

Scenario: Login with wrong credentials
    Given I have login "login" and password "pass"
    When I try to login
    Then the exception with message "Some message" must be thrown
```

Or maybe it's better to stick with simple unit testing for such tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the users of your deliverable were dentists, then a scenario would have to be written from the point of view of a dentist, and understandable to him. If the users are all programmers, then it must be written from the viewpoint of a programmer. The fact that programmers will *also* be the ones who create the system is irrelevant, just like the fact that the programmers of the hypothetical first system also occasionally visit dentists. It's always the *role* that someone fulfills in a particular interaction that determines what to present and how, not the entirety of their personality.

Comment: I would go one step further: The scenarios should be written from the viewpoint (and in the language) of the *users* of the deliverable, be they dentists or programmers. Even if programmers are your users, they might use different terms and/or scenarios than the implementers would.

Comment: One thing to note that the programmers using your API are **NOT** you. The common trap when writing APIs (especially dog-fooded APIs) is you can fall into the trap of writing features for the person programming the API, but you should be programming for the person using the API. Nobody cares about the person developing the API. Writing features for them typically ends up putting alot of YAGNI requirements into the code.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I work in a small company and I actually will be one of the programmers that will use this API :) But I understood your point of view. Thanks!